# Unable to send email from AWS EC2 instance using mailx

Tags: amazon-ec2, mailx

I want to email myself an error log stored on AWS EC2 instance to help me troubleshoot an issue I am having while trying to remote desktop to the machine. This is a one time thing - I am not going to use EC2 to send emails reguarly from a web app etc. Reading [this](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/faqs/) link it says:

> Q: Are there any limitations in sending email from EC2 instances?
>
> Yes. In order to maintain the quality of EC2 addresses for sending
>   email, we enforce default limits on the amount of email that can be
>   sent from EC2 accounts. If you wish to send larger amounts of email
>   from EC2, you can apply to have these limits removed from your account
>   by filling out this form.

So this means I should be able to send a few emails without any problem. I tried emailing myself the error log like this:

```
cat log.txt | sudo mailx me@yahoo.com
```

It does not give any error but the file is never delivered. I think its never send out. How can I troubleshoot this? I am not familiar with unix. Reading around a bit `mailq` shows me this:

```
-Queue ID- --Size-- ----Arrival Time---- -Sender/Recipient-------
6295B488F5    37616 Wed Apr  1 02:10:30  root@ip-xxx-xx-x-xx.us-west-2.compute.internal   a@yahoo.com
```

I don't know what to do beyond this.

EDIT: Its funny. I did get the messages delivered to my inbox but it was only after about 2 days.

Comment: what happens when you type `which mailx` at the commandline? do you have postfix or sendmail installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have ssh access to the box,just use scp to get the file.  E.g., from OSX command line:

```
scp -i your.pem ubuntu@ec2-1-2-3-4.compute-1.amazonaws.com:your_file your_file
```

This is for "ubuntu" login, with "your_file" in home directory, saved to same name locally.  I guess there are GUI versions also, e.g., I used to use Putty on Windows.

Comment: thanks. more info here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AccessingInstancesLinux.html